# Azure DevOps project notifications settings not delivering to custom email address

Tags: azure-devops

I've made small changes in my project's notifications config:

In "Delivery settings" selected "Deliver to email address"
[image]
This email address is a distribution list that consists of several members
Now the notification configuration is like this:
[image]

However, notifications aren't delivered to this DL.

I'm wondering what may cause this misbehaving? Or I'm doing something wrong?..

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons for not receiving email notifications:

- Email server might be down, unreachable or rejected authentication
- Email was delivered to an unchecked folder
- Subscription is disabled or opt-out
- Event might not be matching with subscription key filter conditions
- Subscription is defined to not send emails to the initiator of an event
- Organization level `do not deliver` setting is impacting email delivery
- The team or group level [do not deliver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops#check-do-not-deliver-setting-for-your-team-or-group) setting is impacting email delivery
- You're not a member of the group or team receiving the email
- You're a member of an Azure Directory (AD) group and the subscription contains a @Me clause
- You don't have permission to view the event details, which are included in the email

To check each and every condition and to troubleshoot your settings, consider the below link for walk through the procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops